# Twilio: Receive SMS and Do Something With Body Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm having a tough time understanding Twilio. I've read the docs, and plan to read them again, but I was hoping for some pointers. I am using Ruby on Rails for my application.

What I want to do is to be able to receive a text message from a user with some body text. Then, I want to be able to save that text in my model some how. How do I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Did you go through the Twilio SMS quickstarts.  Thats probably the best way to get the concepts down:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms

If you did and still had trouble getting started, I'd love to hear what you think we could be doing better.  Drop me a line at devin [at] twilio [dot] com

Comment: Hey Devin, I did manage to go through the quickstarts eventually, and they definitely helped a TON. Thank you and Twilio for putting together such a great set of docs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Twilio number can be associated with a callback URL which it will send a POST request to when it receives an SMS. This callback URL should be customized to point to a controller in your app that you will use for processing SMS. From there, you can just read the params hash for details of the SMS message received. Of note: `params['From']` and `params['Body']`. Store the text from those params into any model you like!

Twilio Callback URL

```
http<s>://<your domain.com>/sms
```

Route

```
resource :sms, only: :create
```

Controller

```
class SmsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :force_ssl # You may need this if your app uses https normally

  def create
    # Do something with params['From'] -- contains the phone number the SMS came from
    # Do something with params['Body'] -- contains the text sent in the SMS

    # <Reponse/> is the minimum to indicate a "no response" from Twilio
    render xml: "<Response/>"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

user2515526,

Recently I set up my first Rails app that draws upon some Twilio Functionality - primarily that of receiving, processing, and responding to SMS messages - and I agree: from a noob's perspective, the Twillio documentation can definitely be cleared up ^^.

I found [this](https://github.com/crabasa/twilio-rails-demo) git repo to be **extremely** helpful. The guy essentially walks you through pretty much all you need to know to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body of an sms message just like you would get the content from a textbox in a web application. 
In python, it would be

```
mybody = request.args.get('body')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node Express, here's a snippet that worked for me:

```
app.post('/respondToMessage', function(req, res) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    console.log('sms message =', req.body.Body);
    twiml.message('respondToMessage');
    res.type('text/xml');
    res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

You're parsing for the JSON attribute **Body** from a response that usually looks like this:

```
{
   "ToCountry": "",
   "ToState": "",
   "SmsMessageSid": "",
   "NumMedia": "",
   "ToCity": "",
   "FromZip": "",
   "SmsSid": "",
   "FromState": "",
   "SmsStatus": "",
   "FromCity": "",
   "Body": "The attribute you're parsing for",
   "FromCountry": "",
   "To": "",
   "MessagingServiceSid": "",
   "ToZip": "",
   "NumSegments": "",
   "MessageSid": "",
   "AccountSid": "",
   "From": "+",
   "ApiVersion": ""
}
```